# Google maps js marker does not show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to implement a google map into a project but i cannot get the marker to show up on the map. Here is my code:

The HTML:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#map-canvas {
    border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
    height: 445px;
    width: 100%;  
}
```

JS:

```
function initialize() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: 40.6700, lng: -73.9400};
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
        var mapOptions = {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 13,
            navigationControl: true,
            mapTypeControl: true,
            scaleControl: true,
            scrollwheel: false,
            draggable: true,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng,
                map: map-canvas,
                icon: "../images/map.png",
                title: 'Find us here!'
            });
        marker.setMap(map-canvas);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I have read some threads and tries multiple code variants and nothing seems to work. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post this as a codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your marker's icon is available, you need to set the `map` property of the [marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) to a [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) object.  In your code that is `map` not `map-canvas`

Change:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map-canvas,
            icon: "../images/map.png",
            title: 'Find us here!'
        });
    marker.setMap(map-canvas);
```

To:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: "../images/map.png",
            title: 'Find us here!'
        });
    marker.setMap(map);
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rv2bm7jh/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatLng = {
    lat: 40.6700,
    lng: -73.9400
  };
  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
  var mapOptions = {
    center: myLatLng,
    zoom: 13,
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    scaleControl: true,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png",
    title: 'Find us here!'
  });
  marker.setMap(map - canvas);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  height: 445px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change :

```
 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
```

To :

```
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```